# Protocategory generates category uniquely (up to isomorphic)?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I am reading Johnstone's "Sketches of an Elephant", and I get stuck in the construction of an idea of a category **B** is *structured over* a category **C**.

Johnstone introduces *protocategory* to give this idea, and he mentions the key axiom that
if $g: A \rightarrow B$ and $f: B \rightarrow C$, there is exactly ont $h$ satisfying $h: A \rightarrow C$ and $ f \circ g = h $.

But I don't get how protocategory generates category and the uniqueness of the generated category too.

I mean, if a category **B** is generated by a protocategory **C**, is a category **B** unique (up to isomorphism or something like that)?

Comment: The category generated by a protocategory is unique by construction, just like any other explicit mathematical construction of an object: you write down what the objects, the hom-sets, and the operations are.  What are you worried about?

Comment: Maybe [the n-lab description](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/protocategory) will help? There it's quite clear that each protocategory really does generate a unique category: as Mike says, it lays out specifically what the objects, morphisms, and composition operation are (see the last bulletpoint in section 2).

Comment: Okay, I misunderstand the idea of protomorphism and source-target predicate.

Comment: I considered "doing generate category" as "taking a kind of closure of source-target predicate. But now I have just noticed that protomorphisms are the same as morphisms except they are not directly related to (source-target) specific objects.